# Why is my orbit/watermaster fuse blowing with brand new solenoid?

Tags: circuit-breaker, sprinkler-system, timer

I have a watermaster (now orbit) timer.

I replaced a bad solenoid with "the only orbit solenoid that fits the hole" at home depot, the Orbit 57861 13V

Now my fuses in the timer immediately blow when I try to use this brand new solenoid, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that new solenoid was a "13V DC solenoid for battery operated timer" and my timer is a watermaster "24v AC" wired timer.

Which apparently causes fuses to blow.  Using the right solenoid it works now.  I had better luck finding them at Lowes, YMMV, they do exist anyway (small head 24V solenoids).

Comment: I was curious what would happen, thank you for doing the experiment.